# Go - errors.As() not recognising type

Tags: go

I am using a helper function to decode JSON.  It returns a custom error type that is populated with the reason why it could not parse the JSON and the HTTP code I should return.

```
package dto

type MalformedRequestError struct {
    Status  int
    Message string
}

func (mr *MalformedRequestError) Error() string {
    return mr.Message
}
```

One of the first things I do when decoding the body is to check that the client has correctly set the Content-Type header.

```
package webhandlers

func decodeJSONBody(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, dst interface{}) error {
    if r.Header.Get("Content-Type") != "" {
        value, _ := header.ParseValueAndParams(r.Header, "Content-Type")
        if value != "application/json" {
            Message := "Content-Type header is not application/json"
            return &dto.MalformedRequestError{Status: http.StatusUnsupportedMediaType, Message: Message}
        }
    }
    ... etc ...
```

I try to use `errors.As()` to check that the function is returning my custom error, but it is not working.

```
package webhandlers

func (i *InternalTokenHandler) Post(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    type postRequest struct {
        Google_id_token string
    }
    // parse request data
    var parsedRequest postRequest
    err := decodeJSONBody(w, r, &parsedRequest)
    if err != nil {
        // outputs *dto.MalformedRequestError
        fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%T", err))
        var mr *dto.MalformedRequestError
        if errors.As(err, &mr) {
            http.Error(w, mr.Message, mr.Status)
        } else {
            log.Println(err)
            http.Error(w, http.StatusText(http.StatusInternalServerError), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        }
        return
    }
    .... more code ...
```

I have checked that the type of the error is `*dto.MalformedRequestError`, but my code is always reaching the `else` block and returning the generic server 500 error.

What am I missing - why is errors.As() not recognizing the error type?

Comment: Please make this the answer - I had imported the dto from another one of my services.  So stupid of me - thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```golang
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

type MalformedRequestError struct {
    Status  int
    Message string
}

func (mr *MalformedRequestError) Error() string {
    return mr.Message
}

func decodeJSONBody(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, dst interface{}) error {
    return &MalformedRequestError{Status: http.StatusUnsupportedMediaType, Message: "bad json"}
}

func main() {
    err := decodeJSONBody(nil, nil, nil)

    var mr *MalformedRequestError
    if errors.As(err, &mr) {
        fmt.Println("ok:", mr.Message, mr.Status)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("not ok:", err)
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/CWe9mVp7QOz)

The only reason I can think of that would cause your code to fail, if it really does fail, is that the `dto` package used by `decodeJSONBody` is not the same as the `dto` package used by `InternalTokenHandler.Post`, hence the two error types would be different.

Note that even different versions of the same package count as different packages and types declared in those are not *identical*.